# Question about independence of random variables, theorem 10.1.(c), Jacod and Protter

Tags: probability

the following solution to the problem 15.4 was given by my instructor, but I don't understand the independence argument. We are given that the independent $X_i$ and $N$ are independent, but theorem 10.1.(c) to be used would, from what I can see, require $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_i)$ and $Y$ to be for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Do we have this, or am I missing something? And in that case, how would one go about solving the problem?

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, all the $X_i$ are independent from each other and from $N$. Is there are certain spot in the solution you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, does all $X_i$ and $Y$ being independent imply $(X_1, \ldots, X_i)$ and $Y$ being independent for all $i$? Cause isn't that what we need to apply theorem 10.1.(c)?

Comment: Description is fuzzy.  $Y_i$ does not appear.  $S_N$ and$S_n$  are identical for $n=N$.  Why both?

Answer (score 1):

The statement that $\ N\ $ is "independent of the sequence" means that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(N\in A, (X_i\big)_{i=1}^\infty\in B\right)= \mathbb{P}\big(N\in A \big) \mathbb{P}\big(\big(X_i\big)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in B\big)
$$
for all $\ A\subset\mathbb{N}\ $ and all Borel subsets $\ B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^\infty\ $.  It's a stronger statement than one which merely says that  $\ N\ $ is pairwise independent of  $\ X_i\ $ for all $\ i\ $.  When applying Theorem $10.1.$(c), you need to take the random variable $\ X\ $ to be the *entire sequence* $\ \big(X_i\big)_{i \in\mathbb{N}}\ $, the function $\ f\ $ to be given by
$$
f\big(\big(x_i\big)_{i \in\mathbb{N}}\big)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\ ,
$$
and $\ g\ $ to be the identity function on $\ \mathbb{N}\ $. Then $\ f\left(\big(X_i\big)_{i \in\mathbb{N}}\right)=S_n\ $, and theorem $10.1.$(c) tells you that this is independent of $\ g(N)=N\ $.  This is all you need to get
$$
\mathbb{P}(S_n\in A\,|\,N=n)= \mathbb{P}(S_n\in A) \mathbb{P}(N=n)\ .
$$
If you had, in fact, needed independence of $\ N\ $ and $\ \big(S_n\big)_{n \in\mathbb{N}}\ $, you could have gotten that just as well,
by taking $\ f\ $ to be given by
$$
f\big(\big(x_i\big)_{i \in\mathbb{N}}\big)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)_{n \in\mathbb{N}}\ .
$$